# Hibernate 3.6.0.Final ClassNotFoundException ReflectionManager

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, persistence

I get an error: 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager

i'n pom.xml i have:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and in spring-context.xml i have:

```
<bean id="sampleDataSource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName">
    <value>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</value>
  </property>
  <property name="url">
    <value>
      jdbc:hsqldb:file:/spring/db/springdb;SHUTDOWN=true
    </value>
  </property>
  <property name="username" value="sa"/>
  <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="sampleSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="sampleDataSource"/>
  <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"  />
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">0</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

please help!

The complete stack trace:

```
28/12/2010 20:45:33 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Wireless WLAN Card;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\smartmontools\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin
28/12/2010 20:45:35 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:jsf2demo' did not find a matching property.
28/12/2010 20:45:39 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
28/12/2010 20:45:39 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
28/12/2010 20:45:39 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 8457 ms
28/12/2010 20:45:39 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
28/12/2010 20:45:39 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.5
28/12/2010 20:46:12 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
28/12/2010 20:46:12 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
28/12/2010 20:46:12 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Dec 28 20:46:12 IST 2010]; root of context hierarchy
28/12/2010 20:46:12 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml]
28/12/2010 20:46:13 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1695ee2: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,helloWorldBean,service,dataSource,sampleDataSource,sampleSessionFactory,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
28/12/2010 20:46:13 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
28/12/2010 20:46:13 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1695ee2: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,helloWorldBean,service,dataSource,sampleDataSource,sampleSessionFactory,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
28/12/2010 20:46:13 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4544)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1035)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1035)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:442)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:674)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:596)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newConfiguration(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:813)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:549)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1671)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
    ... 42 more
28/12/2010 20:46:13 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4544)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1035)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1035)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:442)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:674)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:596)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newConfiguration(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:813)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:549)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1671)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
    ... 42 more
28/12/2010 20:46:13 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.0 (SNAPSHOT 20100903) for context '/jsf2demo'
28/12/2010 20:46:15 com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
28/12/2010 20:46:15 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor 
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/localhost/jsf2demo/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
28/12/2010 20:46:15 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
28/12/2010 20:46:15 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/jsf2demo] startup failed due to previous errors
28/12/2010 20:46:15 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
28/12/2010 20:46:15 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/jsf2demo] registered the JBDC driver [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
28/12/2010 20:46:15 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/jsf2demo] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [com.sun.faces.util.Util$1@ff4569]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{com.sun.faces.patternCache={ = }}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
28/12/2010 20:46:15 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
28/12/2010 20:46:15 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
28/12/2010 20:46:15 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 36714 ms
```

Comment: Check if hibernate-core.jar is present in the webapp.

Comment: i fixed it by adding `hibernate-commons-annotations.jar` to my build path in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i found the solution:
In the session factory deleting the line:

```
<property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
```

eliminates the exceptions.
BTW, no need to include explicitly hibernate-commons-annotations since it comes with
hibernate-entitymanager (and probably hibernate-core) in version 3.6.0.Final
The main thing here is that many thing changed in hibernate 3.6.0 and thus the configurations have changed also.